# Async BehaviorSubject for Rust

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I need a data container for sharing mutable state in an asynchronous context similar to the [BehaviorSubject](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects/behaviorsubject) in RxJs. More precisely, I need a struct `BehaviorSubject<T>` containing an item of type `T` such that:

- We can clone the container and pass it to other threads/tasks (i.e. the container needs to implement `Clone + Send + Sync` (I need it as part of an axum app state).
- We can turn the container into a stream for observing the underlying `T`. This stream starts by sending the current value and then sends all updates (intermediate events don't matter - I only need the latest item at any time).
- We can get/set the item inside the container. On each mutation, the item gets mutated in all cloned containers, and all streams are notified.

I have an implementation (see below) which almost works as intended, but still has some bugs:

- Slow receivers seem to slow down other receivers (at least in the beginning - I don't really understand what is going on here).
- Cleanup does not work properly: When turning all but one clones of a `BehaviorSubject` into streams and dropping the last one, I would expect all streams to stop. But that does not seem to happen.

Any suggestions (implementation improvements / alternative approaches / other libraries) are highly appreciated!

```rust
use futures::Stream;
use std::sync::Arc;
use tokio::sync::{
    broadcast::{channel, error::RecvError, Sender},
    Mutex,
};

#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct BehaviorSubject<T> {
    value: Arc<Mutex<T>>,
    sender: Sender<T>,
}

impl<T: Clone> BehaviorSubject<T> {
    pub fn new(value: T) -> Self {
        let (sender, _) = channel(1);
        BehaviorSubject {
            value: Arc::new(Mutex::new(value)),
            sender,
        }
    }

    pub async fn get_value(&self) -> T {
        self.value.lock().await.clone()
    }

    pub async fn set_value(&self, new_value: T) {
        let mut cur_value = self.value.lock().await;
        *cur_value = new_value.clone();
        _ = self.sender.send(new_value);
    }

    pub fn into_stream(self) -> impl Stream<Item = T> {
        async_stream::stream! {
            let mut rx = self.sender.subscribe();
            yield self.value.lock().await.clone();
            loop {
                match rx.recv().await {
                    Ok(value) => yield value,
                    Err(RecvError::Lagged(_)) => (),
                    Err(RecvError::Closed) => break,
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is what you're looking for [`tokio`'s `watch` channel](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/sync/watch/index.html)?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman: No, I actually need multi-producer + multi-consumer: Any clone of the container must be capable of mutating the value inside, and of observing the value. (It would also be okay to split the container into a producer/consumer pair, but that wouldn't change that fact, I think)

Comment: You can wrap the `Sender` with `Arc`. It is `Send + Sync`, and its `send()` requires only `&self`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman: You are right! Is this an actual improvement, or is `broadcast::Sender<T>` already based on `Arc`?

Comment: [`broadcast::Sender` does use an `Arc`](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.28.2/src/tokio/sync/broadcast.rs.html#166), but broadcast is not what you want: it waits for all receivers to receive the message.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman: Right. It actually seems quite buggy if one stream is much more slowly received than others. I also noticed that streams don't stop when the last sender gets dropped. Don't really understand what is going on. Suggestions are very much appreciated.

Comment: After second though, `watch` is not what you want because it'll dismiss all but the last message. I don't think there is something built-in like what you want.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman: Dismissing intermediate events is perfectly fine for me (that is why I set the capacity of the broadcast stream to 1). To my understanding, the problem with the `watch` channel is that only one thread can send values.

Comment: Yes, but as I said, you can wrap the `Sender` in `Arc`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman: Sorry, I misunderstood when you mentioned it the first time. You are right: I think I have found a bug free implementation of `BehaviorSubject<T>` based on `watch`. I will post it later after further testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Chayim Friedman's suggestions, I found a very slim (and hopefully bug free) implementation for `BehaviorSubject<T>` by wrapping tokio's `watch` channel:

```rust
use futures::Stream;
use std::sync::Arc;
use tokio::sync::watch::{channel, Receiver, Sender};
use tokio_stream::wrappers::WatchStream;

#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct BehaviorSubject<T> {
    sender: Arc<Sender<T>>,
    receiver: Receiver<T>,
}

impl<T: 'static + Clone + Send + Sync> BehaviorSubject<T> {
    pub fn new(value: T) -> Self {
        let (sender, receiver) = channel(value);
        Self {
            sender: Arc::new(sender),
            receiver,
        }
    }

    pub fn get_value(&self) -> T {
        self.receiver.borrow().clone()
    }

    pub fn set_value(&self, value: T) {
        _ = self.sender.send(value)
    }

    pub fn into_stream(self) -> impl Stream<Item = T> {
        WatchStream::new(self.receiver)
    }
}
```

**Use case:**

Just in case anyone is interested in use cases: I plan to use this struct for sharing a common mutable resource through a web server. It is designed for being used in that way:

```rust
use axum::{
    extract::{Path, State},
    http::StatusCode,
    response::{
        sse::{self, KeepAlive},
        IntoResponse, Sse,
    },
    routing::get,
    Json, Router,
};
use behavior_subject::BehaviorSubject;
use futures_util::StreamExt;

#[derive(Clone)]
struct AppState {
    subject: BehaviorSubject<u32>,
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let app = Router::new()
        .route("/get", get(value_getter))
        .route("/set/:value", get(value_setter))
        .route("/stream", get(stream_handler))
        .with_state(AppState {
            subject: BehaviorSubject::new(0),
        });

    axum::Server::bind(&"127.0.0.1:8080".parse().unwrap())
        .serve(app.into_make_service())
        .await
        .unwrap()
}

async fn value_getter(State(state): State<AppState>) -> impl IntoResponse {
    Json::from(state.subject.get_value())
}

async fn value_setter(Path(value): Path<u32>, State(state): State<AppState>) -> impl IntoResponse {
    state.subject.set_value(value);
    StatusCode::OK
}

async fn stream_handler(State(state): State<AppState>) -> impl IntoResponse {
    Sse::new(
        state
            .subject
            .into_stream()
            .map(|val| sse::Event::default().json_data(val)),
    )
    .keep_alive(KeepAlive::default())
    .into_response()
}
```